# Spring Batch Header Handler issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have created a Header Handler class where I put the value of the header into the Execution context.The handleLine,beforeStep and afterStep methods have been implemented.But when I run the application the handleLine method gets invoked and I get the value of the header.But for some reason,beforeStep and afterStep don't get invoked.I am not sure why.Below is the code snippet:

```
public class HeaderLineHandler implements LineCallbackHandler,StepExecutionListener {

        StepExecution stepExecution;
        public void handleLine(final String headerLine) { 
            stepExecution.getExecutionContext().put("headerKey",headerLine);
        }

        @Override
        public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
            ExecutionContext jobContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
            System.out.println("Header value" + (String)jobContext.get("headerKey"));

            return  stepExecution.getExitStatus(); 
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
        }
}
```

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Since afterStep does not get triggered,I am unable to check the value.Also,I have defined a promotionListener in the spring context file.

Comment: Thanks @LucaBassoRicci.That worked.Although I did not quite understand why a Handler needs to be registered as a listener.I thought only Listeners which we create separately need to be registered.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Register `HeaderLineHandler` as step listener.
This has to be done because - as written somewhere in doc - only first-class items (steps, readers, writers and processors for sure, others i don't remember now) are automatically registered as listeners by framework.

Comment: Understood.Thank you for the info.I accept your answer.